# How do I fix an assembly referencing an old (beta) version of .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, assemblies

I'm trying to compile a project in Visual Studio 2010.  It worked fine in Visual Studio 2008 but 2010 is giving the following error:

> The primary reference "TiS.Core.eFlowAPI" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "2.0.3600.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.

I've tracked down the culprit to MDbgCore.dll.  This assembly is included (in a dependency chain) and it is looking for mscorlib 2.0.3600.0.

After doing some research it looks like that is a beta version of .NET 2.0.

How do I solve this problem?  I don't have access to the code of this third party DLL (ie. TiS.Core.eFlowAPI).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved it.  Perhaps the wrong way but I used [Reflexil](http://reflexil.net/) to modify the offending DLL so it pointed to the correct version of .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new project and referencing the correct assembly.  then copy and paste the code into your project

Comment: My project (targeting .NET 3.5) references TiS.Core.eFlowAPI.dll.  The problem is that TiS.Core.eFlowAPI.dll references other DLLs including MDbgCore.dll.  It is this DLL that is looking for mscorlib from .NET 2.0.3600.

Answer (score 0):

You can try assembly redirection. I'm unsure about if this is the solution for you, but I believe that can be something to check:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx

Comment: Maybe (probably) I was doing it incorrectly but this didn't seem to work for me...

Comment: Well, we had to try that, hadn't we? :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I was able to resolve it by renaming / deleting the `MdbgCore.dll` in the target directory.